# Adjectives before or after classifiers in Chinese

Tags: measure-word, word-order

So far, I have learned that adjectives come after classifiers and before nouns.

For example,

一只黑猫:a black cat

During my studies, I came across this sentence:

他在**自己家附近**的一间办公室里工作。

In this sentence, 自己家附近 acts as an adjective for 办公室, but has come before the classifier 间.

Is
他在一间自己家附近的办公室里工作。
wrong?

I have also seen
这是简单的一天。
as another example.

Would
这是一简单的天。
be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are a couple of issues here, because all modifiers and all "nouns" are not treated the same.

First, the usual order is (number/determiner)(measure word)(adjective)(noun).  If there is a relative clause ending in 的 used as a modifier, it can be placed either before the number slot or before the adjective slot.  Therefore you can say either:

> 那个戴眼镜的很高的人,or
>
> 戴眼镜的很高的那个人

In a given phrase, one order or the other may be clearer or allow you to omit or at least not repeat 的.  Repeating 的 is often awkward or bad style.

> I have also seen 这是简单的一天。 as another example.
>
> Would 这是一简单的天。 be wrong?

The problem with 天 is that it is both a free noun meaning "sky" and a measure word meaning "day."  Its meaning is also vaguer than a translation as "day" might indicate.  In the quoted example 天 in the meaning of "day" is "fortified" by adding 一 before it and forming a two-syllable word to allow the two syllables to be used as a free noun together in this meaning.  The placement of 简单的 is then unremarkable.  If you replaced 一天 with 日子, I believe you would say: 一个简单的日子

Answer (score 1):

There is no mistake that an adjective can be added before a noun to modify the noun. For example, "我今天吃了好几碗白米饭", "明天将是一个下雨的天"

Comment: Never heard any 一个XX的天 before...一天 is often used as a complete word. 个 is OK. 这是一个阴沉的雨天.

Comment: Although this is grammatical, the Chinese rarely say it.

Comment: We usually say "这雨天很阴沉"

Comment: 这雨天很阴沉 and 这是一个阴沉的雨天 express a different focus. 这雨天很阴沉 is grammatical, the Chinese rarely say it.

Answer (score 1):

> 他在一间自己家附近的办公室里工作. <--right

> 这是一简单的天 <--wrong

> put it in another way,  could be`这是简单的一天`

Answer (score 0):

You are very perspicacious!

他在家附近工作。
他在一间办公室里工作。
他在家附近的一间办公室里工作。
他在一间家附近办公室里工作。

在 ... 里 is a locator, tells us where something happens.
家附近 neighbourhood tells us where the office is.
So we have two locators: one locates the office (家附近的), the other locates the work (办公室里)

The location of the office and the work coincide, but neighbourhood is less specific than office